# What is the length of bcrypt hash output?

Tags: javascript, node.js, hash

In `Javascript` it is possible to create hash using the `bcrypt` library as follows:

```
const hashed = await bcrypt.hash('input', salt);
```

My question is what is the length of `hashed`?

**My guess:**
Since it adds the salt to output, I guess the length of `hashed` should be something like:

```
length_hash = length(salt) + F(input)
```

However, I could not find a formula for `F`.

**Why do I need it?**
I need to know what the maximum length will be in advance to set a `max_length` on the corresponding field in database.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Thats kind of easy to find out on your own. Run couple codes with different passwords/salts and `console.log` the output, then check the length

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. I am not sure the length of output is always the same. I actually did what you suggest, but my supervisor (code reviewer) suggest that you cannot draw general conclusion based on a few observations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be something related to the bcrypt algorithm not the library itself. Simple search led to this [question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/39849/does-bcrypt-have-a-maximum-password-length)

Comment: Thank you very much. The link that you posted explains the length before hashing, not after.

Comment: My fault. Edited